# Uso de objeto a partir de clase con Delphi

Tags: delphi, instancias

Estoy aprendiendo y hay cosas que no comprendo. Estuve leyendo documentación sobre creación de clases y constructores, etc. Pero no logro comprender el funcionamiento para lo que preciso. Sé que es algo básico y que no estoy comprendiendo, me explico:

Necesito crear el objeto **Perro** a partir de la clase **TPERRO** y utilizarlo de manera independiente como un recipiente para hacerle modificaciones, antes de asignarlo nuevamente al **vector** que contiene una colección de perros. Pero al asignarle a la variable **PERRO**, el objeto `vector[i]` de la misma clase, para poder editarlo y posteriormente volver a guardarlo en el vector, es como que toda modificación en la variable perro, modificara de inmediato la posición del vector.

```
    type
    Tperro = class
    nombre : string;
    raza : string;
end

var
vector : array [1..10] of TPerro;

implementation

procedure Tform1.cargarperros; //cargo los perros
    begin
    vector[1]:= TPerro.create
    vector[1].nombre := 'Cubo';
    vector[1].raza := 'caniche';

    vector[2]:= TPerro.create;
    vector[2].nombre :='Chopper';
    vector[2].raza := 'labrador';
end;

procedure TForm1.edicion; // editar Perro, utilizando el objeto "PERRO" y no directamente desde el vector
var perro : TPerro;
begin

Perro := TPerro.create;
Perro := vector[1]; //asigno los datos de vector[1] a variable PERRO

Perro.name := 'Olmedo'; 
Showmessage('Nombre anterior ' + vector[1].name); //aca el nombre sale "olmedo" (cuando deberia salir "CUBO")
Showmessage('Nombre Nuevo ' + Perro.name); //aca sale nombre "olmedo"

vector[1] := Perro //aca vuelvo al vector, y le asigno las modificaciones en el (recipiente) PERRO.

end;
```

El `showmessage` (*que lo utilizo para mostrarles lo que me sucede*) muestra lo mismo tanto para **PERRO**, como para `vector[1]`, cuando en realidad preciso que el vector que contiene la colección de perros, no se modifique previamente, sin antes verificar el objeto **PERRO** , al cual le hago las modificaciones.

Recuerdo que antes utilizando la clase (**record**) no tenia estos problemas. Pero como necesito agregarle métodos a la clase **TPerro**, preciso utilizarlo como Objeto y no como registro. Aunque no sé si se puede agregar métodos a la clase **record**. Aun así, estoy aprendiendo y preciso entender cómo funciona.

Todo cambio que realice al objeto **PERRO**, se realiza de inmediato también a la posición del array que previamente le asigne. ( `PERRO := vector[1]` ).
Hay algo que no estoy comprendiendo, o no sé si estoy salteándome algo, o debería declarar el método constructor de la clase con algún tipo de especificación.
Espero explicarme bien.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En Delphi todos los *objetos* son creados en el área de memoria llamada *heap* (montón, en español) y lo que tu guardas, cuando realizas una asignación a una variable tipo objeto es una ***referencia***, también conocida como ***apuntador*** a la dirección de memoria donde reside el objeto.

Te recomiendo leer. Si no tienes un buen libro de programación en Pascal, googlea, por ejemplo [punteros en pascal](https://www.google.com/search?q=punteros+en+pascal).

Cuándo haces esto:

```
Perro := TPerro.create;
Perro := vector[1]; //asigno los datos de vector[1] a variable PERRO
```

En la primera línea, creas una nueva instancia de `TPerro` y asignas a la variable `Perro` la dirección de memoria donde se ha creado esta nueva instancia. Se dice que ahora `Perro` *apunta a* la nueva instancia de `TPerro`.

En la segunda línea, NO ocurre una asignación de los valores que están almacenados en los miembros del *perro* al que apunta `vector[1]` a esta nueva instancia de perro, como tu estás asumiendo, sino que lo que ocurre es que ahora la variable `Perro` apunta a la misma dirección a donde apunta `vector[1]` y cualquier cambio que hagas se va a reflejar en ambas (ya que ambas *apuntan* al mismo objeto, que existe una única vez en memoria.

La prueba básica que normalmente se hace para ejemplificar esto es con dos variables, por ejemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.Prueba;
var
  PerroA, PerroB: TPerro;
begin
  PerroA := TPerro.Create();
  try
    PerroA.Nombre := 'Colocho';
    PerroA.Raza := 'Cocker';
    PerroB := PerroA;  //ambos apuntan al mismo objeto;
    ShowMessage(PerroB.Nombre);
    PerroB.Nombre := 'Gangster';
    ShowMessage(PerroA.Nombre);
  finally
    PerroA.Free;
    //después de este punto, PerroA y PerroB apuntan a una 
    //dirección de memoria donde ya no existe el objeto, 
    //no deben utilizarse y si se utilizan el comportamiento es indefinido.
  end;
end;
```

Sin importar el tamaño en memoria de un objeto, la variable que se utiliza para acceder a él va a tener un tamaño fijo (4 bytes en aplicaciones de 32 bits y 8 bytes en aplicaciones de 64 bits).

```
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(SizeOf(vector)));
```

Va a mostrar 40 si compilas tu aplicación para plataformas de 32 bits y 80 si compilas tu aplicación para plataformas de 64.

Si quieres que la nueva variable `Perro` tenga una copia de los valores contenidos en el objeto al que apunta `vector[1]`, tienes que ir miembro por miembro, por ejemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.edicion; 
var 
  perro : TPerro;
begin
  Perro := TPerro.create;
  try
    Perro.Nombre := vector[1].Nombre; 
    Perro.Raza := vector[1].Raza;
    Perro.Nombre := 'Olmedo'; 
    Showmessage('Nombre anterior ' + vector[1].Nombre); 
    Showmessage('Nombre Nuevo ' + Perro.Nombre); 

    Vector[1].Nombre := Perro.Nombre;
    Vector[1].Raza := Perro.Raza; 
  finally
    Perro.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Si observas mi código, notarás que tengo el cuidado de siempre liberar los objetos que voy creando. Esto evita fugas de memoria (también conocidos como *memory leaks*), ya que en Delphi no hay un recolector de basura y es responsabilidad del programador asegurarse de devolver los recursos que ya no se utilizan al sistema.

Me resta solo explicar la diferencia que ves con el comportamiento de los registros, y esta es es porque los registros no son punteros, sino meros contenedores de valores que se comportan como otros tipos de datos primitivos, digamos un entero. Cuando se declara una variable local de tipo registro, el espacio para la estructura completa se reserva en el stack (la pila) y no en el heap (como en el caso de los objetos).

Si quieres crear registros en el *heap*, debes utilizar operadores de punteros, como `^` y `@`, además de las funciones `New()` y `Dispose()` para gestionar la memoria de los mismos, por ejemplo:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

type
  TMiRegistro = record
    Numeros: array[1..100] of Integer;
    Cadenas: array[1..100] of string;
  end;
  PMiRegistro = ^TMiRegistro;

  TMiObjeto = class
    Numeros: array[1..100] of Integer;
    Cadenas: array[1..100] of string;
  end;

var
  Reg: TMiRegistro;
  PReg: PMiRegistro;
  Obj: TMiObjeto;
begin
  Writeln('Reg:  ', SizeOf(Reg));
  Writeln('PReg: ', SizeOf(PReg));
  Writeln('Obj:  ', SizeOf(Obj));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Este programa, compilado para 32 bits produce la salida:

```
Reg:  800
PReg: 4
Obj:  4
```

Comment: Mil gracias por la respuesta. Definitivamente me era necesario empezar a realizar alguna consulta de estas cosas basicas, porque si no es para perderse. Efectivamente, estube leyendo algo y veo que habia un tema de punteros y direcciones de memoria. Me voy a poner a profundizar del tema. Aun asi la respuesta me aclaró meses de tirar codigo al azar. Nuevamente mil gracias

Comment: Un gusto, me alegra ser de ayuda.